# How do i left align an image in desktop view and center it in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, slider, flexbox

I have a site: http://www.mammothnewyork.com/ which is mostly made up of galleries.

I have some images that are in portrait format, (for example if you scroll down to the "Andela" gallery).

**On Desktop:**

I want them to be left-aligned on desktop. i.e. have an image on the left and black on the right. You can take a look at the "Andela" section as it appears on my test server here http://45.55.217.186/ . However, this approach gets messed up on mobile.

**On Mobile:**

I want them to be centered. Like on the current site, http://www.mammothnewyork.com/. However, this approach does not left-align them on desktop.

The images on both the sites mentioned above have been placed on a black by me in Photoshop manually to demonstrate what I am asking. Otherwise the original image itself would just be the without the black background.

I have tinkered around with:
`background: url(img/andela/Andela-01.jpg) no-repeat center center;`
to use `no-repeat left center` but it does not fix my problem for both desktop and mobile.

My current CSS for the Flexbox slider for Andela and that image is:

```
    <section id="andela" class="gallery section wait">

        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="title lighttext">Andela</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="galleryandela" class="slides-wrap fill">
            <div class="slides">

                <div class="slide">
                    <span class="img" style="background: url(img/andela/Andela-01.jpg) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"></span>
                    <p class="lighttext"  style="top:4%;"></p> 
                </div>

                ....
                ....
                .... <!-- TRUNCATED HTML FOR OTHER DIVS  --> 
                ....
                ....

                <!-- slide last -->
                <div class="slide last">
                    <span class="img" style="background: url(img/andela/Andela-20.jpg) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"></span>
                    <!-- <p class="addbg"  style="top:72%;"></p> -->
                </div>

            </div>

            <nav class="pager">
            </nav>

            <!-- <p class="pager-txt">Explore more using the boxes above or the arrows&nbsp;below.</p> -->

        </div>

    </section>
```

Comment: How do you intend to separate desktop from mobile?

Comment: As shown in the answer below, you should use CSS media queries when setting styles for different screen sizes. You will first need to find the screen size that differentiates between mobile and desktop

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 736px) {
  . img {
   margin:0 auto !important;
}
```

For more information check http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp